# Map cannot be fetched in R to look at the US Census map in KY

Tags: r

I am running a R block of code to view the US Census Data in KY and I am getting this error.

`Getting data from the 2017-2021 5-year ACS Fetching data by table type ("B/C", "S", "DP") and combining the result. Error in` map()`: ℹ In index: 1. Caused by error in` rate_sleep()`:
! Request failed after 3 attempts.
Backtrace:

1. tidycensus::get_acs(...)
2. purrr::map_df(...)
3. purrr::map(.x, .f, ...)
4. purrr:::map_("list", .x, .f, ..., .progress = .progress)
5. tidycensus (local) .f(.x[[i]], ...)
6. purrr (local) insist_get_acs(...)
7. purrr::rate_sleep(rate, quiet = quiet)
   Error in map(.x, .f, ...) :
   Caused by error in `rate_sleep()`:
   ! Request failed after 3 attempts.`

This is my code:

```
{r pullonePow, results='hide'}
## ACS5: since 2010, the sensus Bureau releases 5-years average estimates for all geographic areas. 
## each county has a FIPS code

 

my_vars <- c(survey = "acs5", 
             af.am = "B03002_004"
             )

 

black <- get_acs(geography = "tract", year=(2021), 
                  state = "KY", county = c("Madison", "Warren"), geometry = TRUE, 
                 variables = my_vars)
```

Thank you all so much!

I don't understand what exactly it meant by "caused by error in 'rate_sleep()'.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a working API key? If not, you need to set one up with Census, which you can do so here: https://api.census.gov/data/key_signup.html

Once requested, you will shortly get an API key which you can add to your code, which should bypass some of the authentication issues you may be getting.

Comment: The error may also just be due to a faulty internet connection.